# rendering large server-side datasets in jquery datatables

Tags: jquery, ajax, server-side, datatables

I'm using `DataTables 1.9.4` with few plugins (ColVis, ColReorderWithResize and ColumnFiltering). The parameters I'm using for server-side communication are:

- "bServerSide"
- "fnServerData"
- "sAjaxSource"

Now, let's say I have to display 3000 rows with around 25 columns without pagination ("iDisplayLength": -1). The json containing the data weights around 1MB and it takes around second for server to send it to datatables.

The problem is the rendering of those 3000 rows take few seconds (around 5-10, which is unacceptable). On IE, it can take quite more, resulting in "Script doesn't respond" errors.

I wish I could speed this process up somehow - i.e. by showing lets say 100 rows and rendering the rest in background. Is there a better way? I know there's a Scroller plugin - [Scroller](http://datatables.net/extensions/scroller/), but I need all the data available for searching, so scrolling is not an option.

Comment: The Datatables search will scan the full dataset even if you are using pagination.

Comment: Think about the following idea: create the table using pure jquery, showing 50 results. Then add a "show more results" button. Each time the user clicks on this button you load more 50 more rows from the database and append to the already existing table.

Comment: I need to have all the rows drawn for browser searching (Ctrl+F), and that's why I want to render the table in background. It shouldn't take  too much time and I could display some kind of message saying the table is rendering.

Comment: Wouldn't it be better to have a search input and a button? it makes more sense, doen't it?

Answer (score 1):

unfortunately, datatables aren't made for large dataset. The way around it is to use server side processing. Which means you need to implement the data to be returned based on the page index.

here are the examples:
http://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2651/alternative-server-side-php-script
http://www.datatables.net/examples/server_side/server_side.html

Comment: I have implemented backend logic for datatables' server side processing far more complex that the ones you provided. I can't use pagination (**in one specific table**) either, because I need all records drawn at the start.

Comment: please elaborate what you meant when you said you couldn't use pagination. Also, if you going to send all the records(assuming 1000s) to datatable, it will takes sometime for datatable to render the data. the ONLY way around that is to send a small portion of data at a time via serverside processing pagination.