# jQuery datatable large dataset delay

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, datatable

My jQuery datatable is taking a little too long to display some data.

The query is simple.  In the database, running the same query returns the same results in microseconds, regardless of size.

Here is how the query looks in my PHP script:

```
<?php
  $searchCommodity = $_POST['commodity'];

  $select = "SELECT COMM_CODE, KEY_COMM, MOD_DATE, MOD_USER FROM keyTable WHERE KEY_COMM = '$searchCommodity'";
  $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

  $out = array();
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc())
  {
    $out[] = $row;
  }
  echo json_encode($out);
?>
```

Most of the data returned is less than 1000 records.  But there are a few that return more than 10K to 20K records.

This causes a delay in which if the user is using Firefox, they will receive the **"A web page is slowing down your browser.  What would you like to do?"** error message where they have to select 'Stop' or 'Wait'.

Back in my jQuery, here is how I'm sending the parameter to the PHP script:

```
 $('#commoditySelect').on('change', function()
 {
   var commodity = $('#commoditySelect').val();
   $.post('api/searchKeyComms.php', {commodity:commodity}, function(data)
   {
     var table = $('#example1').DataTable();        
     table.clear();
     table.search('').draw();
     var obj = JSON.parse(data);    
     obj.forEach(function(item)
     {
       table.row.add([item.COMM_CODE, item.KEY_COMM, item.MOD_DATE, item.MOD_USER]);
     });
     table.draw();  
   });
 });
```

On the main HTML page, near the bottom, I set the datatable like this:

```
$('#example1').DataTable({
  "dataType": "json",   
  "iDisplayLength": 25,
  "order": [[ 6, "desc" ]],
  "scrollY": 550,
  "scrollX": true,
  "bDestroy": true,
  "stateSave": true
});
```

Is there anything that I can add/change to any of the code above that will improve the performance of the rendering of the datatable?

I found this page:  https://datatables.net/forums/discussion/2651/alternative-server-side-php-script

But I am not doing any concatenations.  As stated above, it's a simple query that I'm using, and in the database, the data is returned quickly.

I even found this page:  [rendering large server-side datasets in jquery datatables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24766749/rendering-large-server-side-datasets-in-jquery-datatables)

But the only thing I got from that page is that datatables are not made for large datasets.  20K doesn't seem too large.

Comment: So you want to show 10K to 20K records in a table? Use pagination or lazy loading!

Comment: Browsers aren't designed to show that much data generally on top of that table rows are the least efficient way to add data - everytime you add a row, the browser has to recalculate the whole table.  If you can't refactor to for server-side paging or infinite scroll, your best bet would be to render the html on the server and do a single update

Comment: @LawrenceCherone - It appears that even though I did not set the datatable for pagination, pagination is still rendered.  When 20K+ records are returned, I can see 928 pages with 25 per page.  Is that why I was downvoted?

Comment: @freedomn-m - I will accept that as an answer.  Thank you.

Comment: your essentially trying todo what Datatables has built in `data_sources => ajax`, but failing because your still placing 10-20k rows on the DOM

Comment: https://datatables.net/examples/data_sources/ajax.html

Comment: You should look into the datatable's ajax load - as I understand it, datatables stores the data for the table then renders DOM rows per-(client-side)-page.  So you provide the *data* to datatables, not the DOM rows.  This will vastly speed up your page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why loop on your $out array since your $row is already an associative array.. No need to loop.. ^_^

```
<?php
      $searchCommodity = $_POST['commodity'];

      $select = "SELECT COMM_CODE, KEY_COMM, MOD_DATE, MOD_USER FROM keyTable WHERE KEY_COMM = '$searchCommodity'";
      $query = mysqli_query($dbc, $select);

      $row = $query->fetch_assoc()
      echo json_encode($row);
    ?>
```

Comment: Could that be the reason for delay?

Comment: try it.. you'll see.. ^_^

Comment: I'm getting this error:  TypeError: obj.forEach is not a function  

Any thoughts?